# Remove the text from "woocommerce-notices-wrapper" at checkout page

Tags: php, checkout, express-checkout

"You have to enter your address first in order to search for Drop-Off location" How to remove this text from Checkout page. [please check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3mZ2.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkr2N.png)
thanks

want to remove the text from checkout page deactived the shipping plugin but still show

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538478/remove-required-validation-once-woocommerce-checkout-field-is-hidden